# ubuntu is not showing files (programs & games) icons

Tags: unity, icons

just shortcuts have an icons in ubuntu but in windows every program has an icon, look at this :

(Power ISO) in Windows :

[image]

(power ISO) in Ubuntu :

[image]

i want to know why this happening in Ubuntu and not in windows

EDIT: #ravery told me that i can give it an icon and this is true, but that means i have to add icons to all my programs!
is there a way to make ubuntu act like windows in this situations?

Comment: give it an icon. windows has an icon built into the program file

Comment: No, there isn't a way to make an OS have all the icons for *emulated* soiftware just like they were running in their native OS. The first step is to use as much as possible software *designed* to run on the OS. Power ISo is a classic example of that: There's nothing this program does that can't be done with native apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to make an OS have all the icons for emulated soiftware just like they were running in their native OS. The first step is to use as much as possible software designed to run on the OS. Power ISo is a classic example of that: There's nothing this program does that can't be done with native apps.